# Java class namespace?

Tags: java, namespaces

so I've recently started learning java but I'm having a little problem:

```
OrcMage.health -= 80;
```

but if you saw all of my code, you'd see that I use the OrcMage class a lot, and I still have a lot to go. Would it be possible to create something like a namespace so I could type `health -= 80;`instead?

Comment: You must be a C++ developer.  Better to learn how to write Java in its proper idiom than try to write C++ in Java.  I hope you don't have a class with lots of public static variables.  Bad design.

Comment: Is this all from within the OrcMage class, or from outside?

Comment: if `health` is a `static` property , you can use static import to access it directly.

Comment: You do realise that unless you're _guaranteeing_ that you only ever have one `OrcMage` (and where would the fun be in that?) doing this is a really bad idea? Astoundingly bad. Indeed, it is good style to have all non-constant variables having no more than package visibility for all non-POJO classes (POJOs are classes that are treated very much like open C++ structs in how they're used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare health as `static` then use

```
import static OrcMage.health;
```